# Получить значение дива

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть дивы A и B, и их родительский див C. Дивов C очень много на странице. Мне нужно при нажатии на определенный див A получить значение дива B, вложенного в тот же див C, что и див A.

Answer (score 1):

Быстрое решение.

```js
$('.a').on('click', function () {
  alert($(this).parents('.c').find('.b').html());
});
```

```css
.c {
    width: 300px;
    
}

.a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.b {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="c">
    <div class="a">1</div>
    <div class="b">2</div>
</div>

<div class="c">
    <div class="a">3</div>
    <div class="b">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. При подписке нет порверки, что `.a` вообще `.c`. 2. Такая подписка создаёт кучу обработчиков, хотя можно обойтись одним. 3. `parents` вместо `closest` снижает эффективность.

Comment: Да, соглашусь с Вами.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").on('click', ".c .a", function() {
    $(this).closest(".c").find(".b").css("background", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=c><div class=a></div><div class=b></div></div>
<div class=c><div class=b></div><div class=a></div></div>
<div class=c><div class=a></div><div><div class=b></div></div></div>
<div class=c><div><div class=a></div></div><div><div class=b></div></div></div>
<div class=c><div><div><div class=a></div></div><div><div class=b></div></div></div></div>
```